# How can I download my Gravatar icon?

Tags: gravatar

I want to download the avatar photo from my [personal Gravatar profile](https://en.gravatar.com/stevoisiak).

I've unsuccessfully tried:

- Clicking the photo on my profile. (*Leads to resized [80x80 image](https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/914d117c8b8f6aca515e05ef658b9a99)*)
- Right-clicking my profile's photo and select ***Save image as*** (*Option not available*)
- Searching the [***My Gravatars***](https://en.gravatar.com/emails/) page.
- Viewing my account's ***[Photo Gallery](https://en.gravatar.com/profiles/edit/#your-images)***.

**Is there a way to download my personal profile icon from Gravatar?**

Answer (score 13):

You can request anyone's avatar with `curl` like this on MacOS X:

```
curl "http://gravatar.com/avatar/$(md5 -q -s nobody@example.com)?s=300" > avatar.jpeg
```

Or like this on Linux:

```
curl "http://gravatar.com/avatar/$(echo -n "nobody@example.com" | md5sum - | cut -d' ' -f1)?s=300" > avatar.jpeg
```

Replacing `nobody@example.com` with your (or anyone else's) email address, and `300` with the pixel size (up to 2048). For example, `s=300` will get you a 300x300 pixel image.

If you don't have access to a Unix command line, or would like to figure out the URL to enter directly, you'll need to generate the MD5 checksum of the email address. You can do that via various online tools, like [this one](https://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/).

Once you have the MD5 checksum, just plug it into the URL. For example, mine is `51e61f099c7b1ac0588ecda69193f75c`, so my Gravatar URL is `http://gravatar.com/avatar/51e61f099c7b1ac0588ecda69193f75c?s=300` for a 300x300 JPEG.

Comment: Nice, however it downloads in JPEG format, not PNG. Do you know how to download PNG? I've tried without success adding .png after the hash before the size.

Comment: If you're using PHP you can use the command md5 to generate the hash.  More instructions here about PNG output https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Comment: It was `png` for me...

Comment: note the hash needs to be lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried getting the link to the image source from the webpage source code (for example via inspect element)? Worked just fine for me.